# Weird Error that I am getting with php

Tags: php, html

So I have a PHP program that a line from a text file. Then it uses that line of text it read to point to another text file

```
$posts = "posts/posts.txt";
$postsLines = file($posts);
$fetchingPost = TRUE;
$postNumber = 0;
$postPointer;
$postPointerString;
$postLines;
$postTag;
$postTitle;
$postContent;
$endCondition = "end";

while ($fetchingPost == TRUE) {

    $endOfFile = strcmp($postsLines[$postNumber], $endCondition);
    if ($endOfFile == 0) {
        $fetchingPost = FALSE;
    }

    if ($endOfFile <> 0) {
        $postPointer[$postNumber] = $postsLines[$postNumber];
        $postLines = file($postPointer[$postNumber]);
        $postNumber = $postNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

And I get this errors when I run it, I am using the WAMP server

Warning: file(posts/leapMotionSandbox.txt ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\noahhuppert\Paralax v2\index.php on line 45

Warning: file(posts/topDownShooter.txt ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\noahhuppert\Paralax v2\index.php on line 45

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of the array returned by `file()` have a newline at the end of each line. This is not a valid filename character on Windows (it's valid on Unix, although it would be perverse to include newlines in a filename).

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.

Your loop can also be simplified greatly. There's no need for the `$fetchingPost` or `$endOfFile` variables, just test for the end in the `while()` condition.

```
while (($line = rtrim($postsLines[$postNumber]) != $endCondition) {
    $postPointer[$postNumber] = $line;
    $postLines = file($line);
    $postNumber++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
$postsLines = file($posts, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: I think Barmar's right. It appears that there's whitespace at the end of the filename. Try var_dump on the filename string and count the number of characters. If that doesn't work, I'd try taking the space out of the source (parent) path.

Comment: I didnt downvote. You have no idea how much you saved me there.